# elasticsearch deletebyquery return only not found

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I try use https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-deletebyquery for delete documents by query. But all time returned me No found.  My usage :

```
client.deleteByQuery({
  index: index,
  type: type,
  body: {
    query: {
      range: {
        timeStamp: {
          gte: "2016-03-05",
          lt: "2016-03-06"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

On return i have:

```
Elasticsearch TRACE: 2016-03-05T11:48:52Z
  -> DELETE ... 9200/amazontest/pageRanktest/_query
  {
    "query": {
      "range": {
        "timeStamp": {
          "gte": "2016-03-05",
          "lt": "2016-03-06"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  <- 404
  {
    "found": false,
    "_index": "amazontest",
    "_type": "pageRanktest",
    "_id": "_query"
```

What's wrong? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

As of ES 2.0, the delete-by-query feature has been [removed from the core](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_removed_features.html#_delete_by_query_is_now_a_plugin) and is now available as a plugin. You can install the [delete-by-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/plugins-delete-by-query.html) plugin on all your ES nodes in order to add support for deleting documents by query.

Install the plugin like this:

```
bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```

And then you can run your code without getting a 404.